# C# Azure function add record but check first if it already exist cosmosdb using IMongoCollection

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following Azure function using C# that creates/adds a student to cosmosdb and it works just fine

```
[FunctionName("CreateStudent")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateStudent(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "student/create")] HttpRequest req,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "school",
            collectionName: "students",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosAccountEnpoint")] IAsyncCollector<Student> studentCollector,
        ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Creating a new student.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(requestBody);

            await studentCollector.AddAsync(student);

            return new OkObjectResult(student);
        }
```

Now the 'issue' with this approach is that if the student doesn't exist it creates it which is the expected behavior, but if the student already exists it updates the record with the latest data I'm submitting.

Did some searching and `IAsyncCollector` only supports the method `AddAsync` which it doesn't have any type of validations. I found that using `IMongoCollection` should work because it has methods which will let me put some validations in place.

I changed the code to the following

```
        [FunctionName("CreateStudent")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> CreateStudent(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "student/create")] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "school",
                collectionName: "students",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosAccountEnpoint")]
            IMongoCollection<Student> studentCollection,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Creating a new student");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(requestBody);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a valid student in the request body");
            }

            var count = await studentCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(s => s.id == student.id);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Student with ID {student.id} already exists");
            }

            var studentexist = student.id;
            await studentCollection.InsertOneAsync(student);

            return new OkObjectResult(student);
        }
```

After this code change i don't get any errors and everything seems to be ok, the problem is that when i run it i get the following error

```
Function 'CreateStudent' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2023-02-13T15:14:55.796Z] The 'CreateStudent' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CreateStudent'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind CosmosDB to type 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1[School.Student]'.
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use something specific for MongoDB, since you're already using the native Cosmos DB SQL API, not the MongoDB API.

Comment: So what you are saying is that i should stick to MongoDB API and do something like `var mongoClient = new MongoClient(MongoConnectionString);
        var schoolDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("students");
        _studentsCollection = schoolDatabase.GetCollection<Student>("students");
await _studentsCollection.InsertOneAsync(student);` 
and get rid of the initialization at the beginning where i call the IMongoCollection?

Comment: Not saying fhat - just pointing out your issue. Note that cosmos DB’s sql api has upsert so… you can look into that as well.

Comment: You could maybe use a Cosmos input binding to retrieve the `CosmosClient` and query the container. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-cosmosclient

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon and NotFound for your help, i will search through that. I'm new to CosmosDB and just trying to learn how to implement it directly from the function initialization, will search for from CosmosClient and MongoDB API

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code to check whether the particular studentId exists in database or not. If studentId does not exists, then the method will create an entry in database else it will return *BadRequest* with message `Student with particular Id already exists`.

```
public class SchoolAPIs
    {
       //Private data members
        private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;
        private Container documentContainer;

   //Constructor implementation to initialize class data members
   public SchoolAPIs(CosmosClient cosmosClient)
        {
            _cosmosClient = cosmosClient;
            documentContainer = _cosmosClient.GetContainer("School", "Students");
        }
        
    [FunctionName("CreateStudent")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStudent(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "student/create")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Creating student data.");
            string requestData = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(requestData);

     var item = new Student
     {
         id = data.id,
         Created= data.Created,
         StudentName = data.StudentName,
         Subject = data.Subject,
         Standard = data.Standard
     };
    if (data == null)
 return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a valid student in the request body");

var studentExists = documentContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<Student>().ReadNextAsync().Result.Where(q=>q.id == data.id).Count();

if (studentExists > 0)
  return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Student with ID {item.id} already exists");
                
await documentContainer.CreateItemAsync(item);
            return new OkObjectResult(item);
        }
}
```

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student 
    {
        public string id {get; set;}
        public DateTime Created {get; set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public string StudentName {get; set;}
        public string Subject {get; set;}
        public int Standard {get; set;}
    }
```

Also, to support David Makogon suggestion in comment section, you can use `UpsertItemAsync` method of Cosmos DB's sql api. Mainly this method used when we want to update existing document and create if document is not present in the collection.

Using try catch blocks/exception handling errors can be handled.

As per comment by Tom W, added implementation of class, constructor and model.

Comment: This sample omits the part that is the problem - creating or injecting `documentContainer`, which is undeclared here.

Comment: @TomW  I have a class named `SchoolAPIs` and this class has below member with parametrize constructor.
`private readonly CosmosClient _cosmosClient;`
`private Container documentContainer;`
 `public SchoolAPIs(CosmosClient cosmosClient) {`
`_cosmosClient = cosmosClient; `
`documentContainer = _cosmosClient.GetContainer("School", "Students"); }`

Comment: Added additional requested details along with the constructor definition and the class.